# how can I restore my site

Tags: backups, files

I mistakedly erased a site from a server with ftp last night. Now luckily, I had a backup from not too long ago. I copied all the files from my back up directory back into my site using `filezilla` (I backed the site up using `wget`). Now when I go to my site, I gert an error like

> **Fatal error**: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'includes/ckeditor.user.inc'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in
>   **/home/content/q/u/a/quaa7882/html/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.module**
>   on line **48**

This error first appeared on my `apps` module. So I copied to `apps` directory out of the `sites/all/modules` directory but then, the same error appears again for the next module alphabetically so I assume it would appear for every single module. I tried to run `update.php` but I get a **Server error** in `Chrome`, it tells me:

> The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://quaaoutlodge.com/update.php. It may be down for maintenance or
>   configured incorrectly.

I'm wondering what might be going on here and how I can retore the site...?

Thank you!

**EDIt1**

The files in my backup directory are:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron 20581 Aug 24  2013 CHANGELOG.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron  2616 Aug 24  2013 ckeditor.api.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron  3867 Aug 24  2013 ckeditor.config.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron  3395 Aug 24  2013 ckeditor.css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron   354 Aug 24  2013 ckeditor.info
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron 21467 Aug 24  2013 ckeditor.install
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron 26478 Aug 24  2013 ckeditor.module
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron   519 Aug 24  2013 ckeditor-rtl.css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron  3749 Aug 24  2013 ckeditor.styles.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron 18092 Aug 24  2013 LICENSE.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron 21347 Aug 24  2013 README.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron 10521 Aug 24  2013 TROUBLESHOOTING.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ron ron  1547 Aug 24  2013 UPGRADE.txt
```

---

**EDIT2**

I actually found my `ckeditor.user.inc` now, it was under `sites/all/libraries/includes/ckeditor.user.inc` instead and this is also where it is on my ftp. It's got a 175 lines of code and I didn't necessarily want to post the complete file unless required. What should I be looking out for?

Comment: Your backup seems to be incomplete. Is the sites/all/modules/ckeditor/includes/ckeditor.user.inc file present in your backup?

Comment: @tunic Hi, no, I have no `ckeditor.user.inc`, the only files present in my backup dir are listed above under **EDIT1**

Comment: In that case then your backup would seem to be out of date and you must have had different code on the live site compared to the backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backup is incomplete. Talk with your hosting company. In the meantime you can try to download fresh copy of ckeditor module, but even if it'll help, you will never know for sure what else is missing.

Comment: I've found my `ckeditor.user.inc`, in the `libraries` direcvtory (rarther than the mnodules), please see **EDIT2** above.

Comment: I ended up restoring a complete backup from my hosting provider... Thx!